# How can I make a reusable field for java swagger api

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a java spring boot rest controller which accepts a java object.

```
@PutMapping(path = "api/v1/examples/{id}/update")
public ResponseEntity<Void> updateExample(@PathVariable("id") String personsId, @RequestBody ExampleDto dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

The ExampleDto looks like this

```
public class Example {

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00", notes = "Date pattern is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ example value 2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00")
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    public String getDate() {
       return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
       this.date = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }
  }
```

This works the way I like it. It generates the swagger file correctly and in the swaggerui It suggests the correct value which my dto can parse with the setDate(String date) method.

But I would like to make a reusable component that I can just add to my api dtos where I wont have to create all the methots.

If I wanted to add multible date fields my code would look like this.

```
public class Example {

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00", notes = "Date pattern is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ example value 2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00")
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    public String getDate() {
       return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
       this.date = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00", notes = "Date pattern is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ example value 2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00")
    private ZonedDateTime dateTwo;

    public String getDateTwo() {
       return dateTwo.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
    }

    public void setDateTwo(String date) {
       this.dateTwo = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    }
  }
```

I would like if I could do something like this.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example {

    private MyDateType date;

    private MyDateType dateTwo;

  }
```

I can already do this. But then my json would look like this.

```
{
 "date": {
            "innerDate": "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00"
         },
 "dateTwo": {
            "innerDate": "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00"
         },
}
```

And I want the json to look like this

```
{
 "date": "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00",
 "dateTwo": "2021-02-18T13:45:07+02:00"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Multiple DTOs that have some common fields?

Comment: I have tried to clarify it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I've not used it, but `@JsonUnwrapped` looks like it may be what you want. [This](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-unwrapped.html) contains an example.

Comment: Yes JsonUnwrapped can solve it. The annoying thing about it is if I want to change the name of the inner date then I have a prefix option. But if I prefix it then the case is not changed on the innerDate so it would be prefixinnerDate instead of prefixInnerDate.
But if no other solution comes up Ill create two components. One with upper start case and one with lower.

Comment: and there are times when I just wanna change the name to something else. Like estimatedTimeOfArrival or something else.

Comment: There's always [mapstuct](https://mapstruct.org/).

Comment: So I tried to add a dto I could reuse and then I made custom serializers and deserializers for it to it would work like an unwrapped value but where I could control the field names. This worked perfectly. But the swagger file was wrong. The example values didnt take the custom serializers and deserializers into account. I dropped that attempt and added a common dto which has a date field inside it. Then it will just have to be wrapped in that dto whenever I use it.